# Why do I get error when I set root to None initially for BST

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

Im getting TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'BST' and 'int' when I initially set root to None(see in code)

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.key = key
        self.lchild = None
        self.rchild = None

    def insert(self,data):
        if self.key is None:
            self.key = BST(data)
            return
        if self.key < data:
            if self.lchild:
                self.lchild.insert(data)
            else:
                self.lchild = BST(data)
        else:
            if self.rchild:
                self.rchild.insert(data)
            else:
                self.rchild = BST(data)
    
    def preorder(self):
        print(self.key)
        if self.lchild:
            self.lchild.preorder()
        if self.rchild:
            self.rchild.preorder()



root = BST(None)

list1 = [20,34,1,3,4,78]
for i in list1:
    root.insert(i)

root.preorder()
```

When I set root to an int it works fine

Comment: I recommend [debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) your code by stepping through it line-by-line. That usually is a pretty quick way to find the cause of issues like this that doesn't rely on internet strangers.

Comment: I have to agree with the above comment.  It's pretty clear what's wrong.  And you'll learn a lot more if *you* figure out what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments say you should debug. They aren't wrong, but maybe it's hard to see how to do that when you don't understand the error.

The error means generally that you are comparing a `BST` to an `int` somewhere and that this is not defined.

Let's have a look at the types by adding

```
print(f"{type(self.key)=},\t{type(data)=}")
```

to the beginning of your `insert` function.

We get:

```
type(self.key)=<class 'NoneType'>,  type(data)=<class 'int'>
type(self.key)=<class '__main__.BST'>,  type(data)=<class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 36, in <module>
    root.insert(i)
  File "tmp.py", line 12, in insert
    if self.key < data:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'BST' and 'int'
```

So apparently we first execute the function correctly once with the `key` being `None` and then again with the `key` being a `BST` object. The `data` is always an `int`.

But you have not defined how an `int` and a `BST` can be compared.

Do you want to do that? Probably not. Because your key is supposed to be an `int`, right?  You have a `BST` but the key inside the `BST` should be an `int`. So you don't need the `BST(data)` when you assign the key in the case where it is none. instead:

```
if self.key is None:
    self.key = data
    return
```

Answer (score -2):

Just set `root = None` initially.

And check `if root == None` in insert method.